# In what files I can change country names of wp-ecommerce plugin?

Tags: plugin-wp-e-commerce

I am using the newest wp-ecommerce plugin and as I am selling to a non-english speaking country I would like all country names listed in my language in the cart. I search and all the files and changed in several files, but it did not help. Maybe, somebody know where I should change country name what it would be in my language in the cart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The various currencies and their associated countries are stored in the database, `{$prefix}wpsc_currency_list`.

Comment: I changed the value in currency_list.php but it did not help. How can I change it at database level?

Comment: it gets added to the database from that file when you install the plugin. if you've already installed it, it doesn't read from that file again. The easiest way is probably via phpMyAdmin.